# Apache Beam Python: How to implement MapState in the python apache beam sdk?

Tags: python, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I am trying to create a stateful ParDo in apache beam that stores a dict of  values and updates that dict with data from subsequent windows. 
The equivalent being [MapState](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/MapState.html) in java.
I have tried to implement it using a custom CombineFn

```
class DictCombineFn(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return {}

    def add_input(self, accumulator, element):
        accumulator[element["key"]] = element["value"]
        return accumulator

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        return accumulators

    def extract_output(self, accumulator):
        return accumulator
```

Which is used in the CombiningValueStateSpec of the following ParDo:

```
class EnrichDoFn(beam.DoFn):

    DICT_STATE = CombiningValueStateSpec(
        'dict', 
        PickleCoder(), 
        DictCombineFn()
    )

    def process(
              self, 
              element,
              w=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
              dict_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(DICT_STATE)
        ):
           asks_state.add(element)
```

However I get the following error during :

> TypeError: '_ConcatIterable' object does not support item assignment

I think this might be as a result of using the wrong coder?
What would be the optimal strategy to implement the aforementioned logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about what this error means, but it does feel like dict type is not supported somehow in this particular process. Did you try to get a list of string i.e. "key:value", and then parse and convert it to a dict in one shot?

Comment: use comments to ask questions like these ; )

Answer (score 0):

Merge accumulators should return one element, not iterable like in your case. You would do similar processing like in add element.